# Как сделать выбор надписи мышкой в консоле?

Tags: c, cmd, c++

Задача такова.

Необходимо создать в **консоли вертикальное меню** и так....чтобы можно было  **с помощью курсора выбрать** тот или иной пункт.

Что нужно использовать? библиотеку? какие функции? что можно придумать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант поковырять исходники [Far manager](http://code.google.com/p/farmanager/). Это по сути и  есть большое меню в конслои windows написное на c++ :)

Answer (score 3):

Если в Линуксе, то есть библиотека ncurse - Она умеет многое, вот [примеры](http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/March2002/article233.shtml), вот [рекомендации](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/index.html), как писать.

Comment: @KoVadim а в windows как?

Comment: можно пощупать библиотеку - http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html

Вариант два - использовать cygwin + ncurses.
Вариант три - перейти на линукс:)